# Maya Python: connect unit conversion to joint list rotate x

Tags: python, maya

For the context of what I'm trying to do, at about 8:04 in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_LgcFCOUoU&t=414s) video Alexandre connects the unit conversion's output to the rotateY (rotateX in my case) to the rest of the joint chain. I am trying to automate this, my script renames the unit conversion nodes and tries(fails) to connect the unit conversion nodes .output to the rest of the twist joint chain's rotateX.

Before I list the errors though, let me tell you how to use this script. Save a .py file in your maya documents (c:\Users\userName\Documents\maya\mayaVer\scripts). When the file is saved, open maya, go to the script editor and paste the following in a blank tab, highlight and hit enter to load the script:

```
import demoScript
import imp
imp.reload (demoScript)
demoScript.gui()
```

for the script itself saved in the .py file it is the following

```
'''
import demoScript
import imp
imp.reload (demoScript)
demoScript.gui()
'''
import maya.cmds as cmds

if cmds.window("buildWin", exists =True):
    cmds.deleteUI("buildWin", window = True)

myWindow = cmds.window("buildWin",t='DS_armOmatic_V5',rtf=1,w=100, h=100, toolbox=True)
column = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)

def gui(*args):
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
    cmds.button(w=300,label='Print Instructions(Check Script Editor)')
    cmds.separator(h=9)
    
    cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns = 3,adjustableColumn=2) 
    cmds.optionMenu('spinePref',label='Select Spine    ',w=125)
    cmds.menuItem( label='ct' )
    cmds.menuItem( label='rt' )
    cmds.menuItem( label='lf' )
    cmds.text(l='spineIncPref')
    cmds.textField('spineIncText',it = '1',editable=True)
    cmds.setParent('..')

    cmds.rowColumnLayout( numberOfRows=1 )
    cmds.optionMenu('axisPref',label='Select Aim Axis',w=300)
    cmds.menuItem( label='X')
    cmds.menuItem( label='Y')
    cmds.menuItem( label='Z')
    cmds.setParent('..')

    cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns = 3,adjustableColumn=2)
    cmds.optionMenu('sidePref',label='Select Side       ',w=168)
    cmds.menuItem( label='lf' )
    cmds.menuItem( label='rt' )
    cmds.menuItem( label='ct' )
    cmds.text(l='IncPref')
    cmds.textField('incText',it = '1',editable=True)
    cmds.setParent('..')

    cmds.colorIndexSliderGrp('controlColor',
        label='Control Color',
        min=0,
        max=31,
        value=1,
        columnWidth=[( 1, 80 ),( 2, 40 ), ( 3, 150 )])

    cmds.floatSliderGrp('pvPlace',field=True,label='Pv Placement',
        fieldMinValue=-100,fieldMaxValue=100,value=0
        ,columnWidth=[( 1, 80 ),( 2, 40 ), ( 3, 150 )])

    cmds.separator()
    
    
    cmds.separator(h=15)
    cmds.text(l="Set number of upper arm twist joints")
    cmds.separator(h=9)
    cmds.intSliderGrp('upArmJntAmount',field=True, minValue=3, maxValue=100, value=6)
    
    cmds.separator(h=15)
    cmds.button(w=300,label= "Block Out Up Arm Twist Chain",c=buildUpTwistProxies)
    cmds.button(w=300,label= "Finalise Up Arm Twist",c=finaliseUpTwistChain)
    cmds.separator(h=15)
    
    
    cmds.showWindow(myWindow)

    
def buildUpTwistProxies(*args):
    axisPref = cmds.optionMenu('axisPref',query=True,value=True)
    sidePref = cmds.optionMenu('sidePref',query=True,value=True)
    incPref = cmds.textField('incText', query=True, text=True)
    armPref = sidePref + incPref + '_'
    
    upArmTwistBase = 'upArmTwistBase_proxyLoc'
    upArmTwistEnd = 'upArmTwistEnd_proxyLoc'
    
    shoulderJNT = armPref + 'shoulder_BIND'
    elbowJNT = armPref + 'elbow_BIND'
    
    twistTargetStart = armPref+'shoulder_twistTarget_start'
    twistTargetEnd = armPref+'shoulder_twistTarget_end'
    
    root = cmds.ls(sl=True)[0]
    child = cmds.listRelatives(root,ad=1,f=True,children=True,type='joint')
    child.append(root)
    child.reverse()
    limbJnt = child
    
    cmds.spaceLocator(n=upArmTwistBase)
    cmds.spaceLocator(n=upArmTwistEnd)
    
    cmds.annotate(upArmTwistBase,tx='snap to shoulder joint')
    cmds.annotate(upArmTwistEnd,tx='snap to elbow joint')
    
    cmds.parent('annotation1',upArmTwistBase)
    cmds.parent('annotation2',upArmTwistEnd)
    
    cmds.setAttr('annotation1.overrideEnabled',1)#enable overide of left eye control shape
    cmds.setAttr('annotation1.overrideDisplayType',2)#enable overide of left eye color, 6 means blue
    
    cmds.setAttr('annotation2.overrideEnabled',1)#enable overide of left eye control shape
    cmds.setAttr('annotation2.overrideDisplayType',2)#enable overide of left eye color, 6 means blue
    
    cmds.parent(upArmTwistEnd,upArmTwistBase)
    cmds.move(0,5,0,upArmTwistEnd)
    
    #cmds.setAttr(upArmTwistBase+'.overrideEnabled',1)#enable overide of left eye control shape
    #cmds.setAttr(upArmTwistEnd+'.overrideColor',17)#enable overide of left eye color, 6 means blue
    
    
    tempCons = cmds.parentConstraint(child[0],upArmTwistBase,mo=False)
    cmds.delete(tempCons)
    
    tempCons = cmds.parentConstraint(child[1],upArmTwistEnd,mo=False)
    cmds.delete(tempCons)
    
    cmds.select(cl=True)
    
    
    
    jntNumber = cmds.intSliderGrp('upArmJntAmount',query=True,value=True)
    
    count = jntNumber  # Amount of joints to create.

    start = upArmTwistBase  # Change to object to start from.
    end = upArmTwistEnd  # Chagne to object to end to.

    steps = 1.0 / (count - 1)  # Will use count to calculate how much it should increase percentage by each iteration. Need to do -1 so the joints reach both start and end points.
    perc = 0  # This will always go between a range of 0.0 - 1.0, and we'll use this in the constraint's weights.
    
    jntChain = ""

    for i in range(count):
        jnt = cmds.joint()  # Create a new joint.
        cmds.setAttr(jnt + ".displayLocalAxis", True)  # Display its orientation.

        constraint = cmds.parentConstraint(start, jnt, weight=1.0 - perc)[0]  # Apply 1st constraint, with inverse of current percentage.
        cmds.parentConstraint(end, jnt, weight=perc)  # Apply 2nd constraint, with current percentage as-is.
        cmds.delete(constraint)  # Don't need this anymore.

        perc += steps  # Increase percentage for next iteration.
        
    cmds.select('joint1')
    
    #list selection to get the joint and their children
    root = cmds.ls(sl=True)[0] # adding a zero bracket makes sure it counts the head of the herarchy too
    child = cmds.listRelatives(root,ad=1,type='joint')
    limbJnt = child
    
    #rename base joint chain auto spine
    for j, name in enumerate(child):
        cmds.rename(name,armPref + 'AJ{0}_upArmTwistJNT_BIND'.format(len(child)-j))
        print(child)
    
    #rename beggining and end joints to start and end respectivly
    child = cmds.listRelatives(root,ad=1,f=True,children=True,type='joint')
    cmds.rename(child[0],armPref +'AJ_END_upArmTwistJNT_BIND')
    cmds.rename(root,armPref + 'AJ_START_upArmTwistJNT_BIND')
    
    cmds.delete(upArmTwistEnd)
    cmds.delete(upArmTwistBase)
    
    cmds.duplicate(shoulderJNT,n=twistTargetStart, parentOnly=True)[0]
    
    cmds.duplicate(elbowJNT,n=twistTargetEnd, parentOnly=True)[0]
    cmds.parent(twistTargetEnd,w=True)
    
    cmds.parent(twistTargetEnd,twistTargetStart)
    
    cmds.setAttr(twistTargetEnd + '.radius', 5.0)
    cmds.setAttr(twistTargetStart + '.radius', 5.0)
    
def finaliseUpTwistChain(*args):
    axisPref = cmds.optionMenu('axisPref',query=True,value=True)
    sidePref = cmds.optionMenu('sidePref',query=True,value=True)
    incPref = cmds.textField('incText', query=True, text=True)
    armPref = sidePref + incPref + '_'
    
    upArmTwistBase = 'upArmTwistBase_proxyLoc'
    upArmTwistEnd = 'upArmTwistEnd_proxyLoc'
    
    clavicleJNT = armPref + 'clavicle_BIND'
    shoulderJNT = armPref + 'shoulder_BIND'
    elbowJNT = armPref + 'elbow_BIND'
    
    twistTargetStart = armPref+'shoulder_twistTarget_start'
    twistTargetEnd = armPref+'shoulder_twistTarget_end'
    
    shoulderTwistOffset = armPref+'shoulderTwist'
    transformShoulderTwist = armPref+'transformShoulderTwist'
    
    twistChainBase = armPref + 'AJ_START_upArmTwistJNT_BIND'
    upArmTwistIK = armPref + 'upArmTwist_ikHandle'
    
    lowerTwistChain = armPref + 'AJ1_upArmTwistJNT_BIND'
    
    upTwistRotDiv = armPref + 'upArmTwist_rotLimit_multDiv'
    unitConvBase = armPref + 'upArmTwist_unitConBase'
    unitConvRot = armPref + 'upArmTwist_unitConRot'
    unitConvHalf = armPref + 'upArmTwist_unitConHalf'
    
    cmds.group(n=shoulderTwistOffset,empty=True,world=True)
    
    tempCons = cmds.parentConstraint(shoulderJNT,shoulderTwistOffset,mo=False)
    cmds.delete(tempCons)
    
    cmds.duplicate(shoulderTwistOffset,n=transformShoulderTwist, parentOnly=True)[0]
    
    cmds.parent(transformShoulderTwist,shoulderTwistOffset)
    
    cmds.parentConstraint(shoulderJNT,transformShoulderTwist,mo=False)
    
    cmds.parent(twistTargetStart,shoulderTwistOffset)
    
    cmds.ikHandle(n=upArmTwistIK,sj=twistTargetStart,ee=twistTargetEnd,sol='ikSCsolver',sticky='sticky')
    cmds.pointConstraint(elbowJNT,upArmTwistIK,mo=False)
    cmds.parent(upArmTwistIK,shoulderTwistOffset)
    cmds.orientConstraint(elbowJNT,twistTargetEnd,mo=False)
    
    cmds.createNode('multiplyDivide',n=upTwistRotDiv)
    cmds.setAttr(upTwistRotDiv+'.operation',2)
    cmds.setAttr(upTwistRotDiv+'.input2X',1)
    cmds.setAttr(upTwistRotDiv+'.input2Y',4)
    
    
    cmds.connectAttr(twistTargetEnd+'.rotateX',upTwistRotDiv+'.input1X')
    listCon = cmds.listConnections(upTwistRotDiv+'.input1X',d=False,s=True)#this list connections only shows incoming connections
    #print (listCon)
    cmds.rename(listCon,unitConvBase)
    
    
    cmds.connectAttr(unitConvBase+'.output',upTwistRotDiv+'.input1Y')
    
    
    cmds.connectAttr(upTwistRotDiv+'.output',twistChainBase+'.rotateX')
    
    listCon = cmds.listConnections(twistChainBase+'.rotateX',d=False,s=True)
    #print (listCon)
    cmds.rename(listCon,unitConvRot)
    
    #cmds.connectAttr(upTwistRotDiv+'.output',unitConvHalf+'.input')
    
    cmds.select(twistChainBase)
    
    root = cmds.ls(sl=True)[0]
    child = cmds.listRelatives(root,ad=1,f=True,children=True,type='joint')
    child.append(root)
    child.reverse()
    limbJnt = child
    
    #print (child)
    
    cmds.connectAttr(upTwistRotDiv+'.outputX',child[1]+'.rotateX')
    listCon = cmds.listConnections(child[1]+'.rotateX',d=False,s=True)
    #print (listCon)
    cmds.rename(listCon,unitConvHalf)
    #cmds.disconnectAttr(unitConvHalf+'.output',child[1]+'.rotateX')
    
    listConTest=cmds.listConnections(lowerTwistChain+'.rotateX',d=False,s=True)
    print (listConTest)
    
    #build FK controls among spine
    fkChild = cmds.listRelatives(lowerTwistChain,children=True,ad=1,type='joint')
    fkChild.append(lowerTwistChain)
    fkChild.reverse()
    fkLimbJnt = fkChild
    print(fkChild)

    #for loop to create along the spine
    for jnt_a, jnt_b in zip(listConTest,fkChild):
         cmds.connectAttr(jnt_a + '.output', jnt_b + '.rotateX')
    '''
    for j in fkLimbJnt:
        
        cmds.connectAttr(unitConvHalf + '.output', fkChild[0] + '.rotateX')
    '''
    
    cmds.parent(twistChainBase,transformShoulderTwist)


    


def setColor(obj, colorPref):  # Requires an object, and the color index to set it as.
    cmds.setAttr(obj + '.overrideEnabled', 1)  # Need to pass an object!!
    cmds.setAttr(obj + '.overrideColor', colorPref)
```

Create two joints and name them "lf1_shoulder_BIND" and "lf1_elbow_BIND", select lf1_shoulder_BIND and hit "Block Out Up Arm Twist Chain" before hitting "Finalize Up Arm Twist" you may have to freeze joint rotation transforms and make sure all joints are oriented with x as the aim axis.

The error comes from line 276, I've tried rewriting the for loop using all manner of different for loops, but I can't crack it. I either get only one joint connected or a whole manner of other errors like

"can only concatenate list (not "str") to list"
"The source attribute 'l.output' cannot be found"

I know how to use a for loop to connect multiple chains, groups, and objects, but when it comes to connecting unitConvHalf's output to everything past the second joint in the helper chain python doesn't play nice.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
cmds.select(twistChainBase)
    
    root = cmds.ls(sl=True)[0]
    child = cmds.listRelatives(root,ad=1,f=True,children=True,type='joint')
    child.append(root)
    child.reverse()
    limbJnt = child
    
    #print (child)
    
    cmds.connectAttr(upTwistRotDiv+'.outputX',child[1]+'.rotateX')
    listCon = cmds.listConnections(child[1]+'.rotateX',d=False,s=True)
    #print (listCon)
    cmds.rename(listCon,unitConvHalf)
    #cmds.disconnectAttr(unitConvHalf+'.output',child[1]+'.rotateX')
    
    cmds.select(lowerTwistChain)
    
    #build FK controls among spine
    fkRoot = cmds.ls(sl=True)[0]
    fkChild = cmds.listRelatives(lowerTwistChain,ad=True,pa=True)
    fkChild.append(fkRoot)
    fkLimbJnt = fkChild
    print(fkChild)
    
    
    #'''
    for j in fkLimbJnt:
        
        cmds.connectAttr(unitConvHalf + '.output', j + '.rotateX')
        # EDIT: Add objects to list.
        
        #ctls.insert(0, ctl)
    #'''

    
    cmds.parent(twistChainBase,transformShoulderTwist)
```

turns out all I had to do was find out an alternate way to introduce the list into the for loop, I dont know exactly what I did though: but if anyone has an explanation I would appreciate it.